# Calling Outlook Script by using an Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Outlook rule, to run a VBA script, that sporadically runs into errors. I know the script works because I've tested the script as a Public Sub.

I don't know why my rule encounters errors since there is no error description for Outlook rule failures. For a workaround, I decided to get my Outlook script running by calling it from Excel.

The error I receive is:

> Run-time error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method.

The references I have on Excel are:

1. Visual Basic For Applications
2. Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
3. OLE Automation
4. Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
5. **Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library**

Outlook references are:

1. Visual Basic For Applications
2. Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library
3. OLE Automation
4. Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
5. Microsoft Form 2.0 Object Library
6. **Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library**

Code for Excel:

```
Public Sub testexcel()

Dim o As Outlook.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set o = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear: On error GoTo 0

If o Is Nothing then
Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

With o
    .Session.Logon
    .Run "testoutlook" ' <--------- Error Line
End With

o.Close
o.Quit

Set o = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Outlook sample code:

```vb
Public Sub testoutlook()

Call MsgBox("HellO")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I believe that the VBA coding compatibility between Outlook and Excel don't have developer functionality. However, I was able to complete my task by taking my VBA macro from Outlook and inserting into an Excel book.

Essentially, I removed any VBA coding from Outlook so everything was able to be completed using Excel. If anyone is interested in the codes please let me know.